# Magento not working with AMEX

Tags: magento2

We have a magento 2.0 website that is not working with AMEX and paypal pro. All other cards are working we are getting an X for CVV mismatch in paypal although API response shows the correct CVV.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely will not help, but I ran across a problem that smells familiar. Using Paypal Payflow's native Magento implementation, AMEX transactions were having issues because AMEX does not support 0.00 authorizations.  This is important because Magento uses a 0.00 auth to get the payment token from Payflow.  We created a customization to allow for a 0.01 authorization for AMEX. It solved the problem.

Comment: Can you please tell how to enable that in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, our problem was also solved when we customized for $1.00 authorization transaction for AMEX. As the $0.00 transaction is not accepted by AMEX.

Thanks

Comment: how to customize that?

Comment: Can you please tell how to enable that in Magento 2?